# How can the AWS Lambda function get the results of parallel functions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, multiprocessing, python-3.8

In my **AWS Lambda function** (*Python 3.8 runtime*), I'm trying to run three different unrelated functions. Each of these three functions returns different results, with different data types. I need to return the results of these three functions that worked in parallel to the main function `lambda_handler`. What do you think is the most effective way to do this?

Now I'm thinking about using a global variable in which I will record the results of three functions. But it seems to me that I can't get these results in the main function `lambda_handler` since they work in different processes. Isn't it?

I think that using `Pipe` would be more appropriate. As I found out `Queue` is not supported in AWS Lambda. Don't you think so?

```
from multiprocessing import Process


results = dict()

def first_function(event):
    # Do something
    global results
    results["first_function"] = True

def second_function():
    # Do something
    global results
    results["second_function"] = 30


def third_function():
    # Do something
    global results
    results["third_function"] = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t"]


def execute_parallel_processes(*functions):
    # Create an empty list to keep all parallel processes.
    processes = list()

    # Create a process per function.
    for function in functions:
        process = Process(target=function)
        processes.append(process)

    # Start all parallel processes.
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # Wait until all parallel processes are finished.
    for process in processes:
        process.join()


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Execute 3 different processes in parallel.
    execute_parallel_processes(
        first_function(event),
        second_function,
        third_function
    )

    print(results)

    return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with [Pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes). Here is a working code snippet:

```
import json
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from typing import *
from functools import wraps

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


def first_function(*args, **kwargs):
    print("first_function")
    pipe = kwargs["pipe"]
    pipe.send({"first_function": True})
    pipe.close()


def second_function(*args, **kwargs):
    print("second_function")
    pipe = kwargs["pipe"]
    pipe.send({"second_function": 30})
    pipe.close()


def third_function(*args, **kwargs):
    print("third_function")
    pipe = kwargs["pipe"]
    pipe.send({"third_function": ["item1", "item2"]})
    pipe.close()


def execute_parallel_processes(functions):
    # Create an empty list to keep all parallel processes.
    processes = []

    # Create an empty list of pipes to keep all connections.
    pipes = []

    # Create a process per function.
    for index, function in enumerate(functions):
        # Check whether the input arguments have keys in their dictionaries.
        try:
            target = function["object"]
        except KeyError as error:
            logger.error(error)
            raise Exception(error)
        try:
            kwargs = function["arguments"]
        except KeyError as error:
            logger.error(error)
            raise Exception(error)

        # Create the pipe for communication.
        parent_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        pipes.append(parent_pipe)
        kwargs["pipe"] = child_pipe

        # Create the process.
        process = Process(target=target, kwargs=kwargs)
        processes.append(process)

    # Start all parallel processes.
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # Wait until all parallel processes are finished.
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    # Get the results of all the processes.
    results = {}
    for index, pipe in enumerate(pipes):
        results = {**results, **pipe.recv()}

    # Return the results of all processes.
    return results


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    functions = [
        {
            "object": first_function,
            "arguments": {}
        },
        {
            "object": second_function,
            "arguments": {"event": event}
        },
        {
            "object": third_function,
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ]
    results = execute_parallel_processes(functions=functions)
    print(results)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```